# Woocommerce product slider doesn't show second image

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

this is my first question on Stackoverflow.

I have a webshop for my clothing company, but I have a issue with my product slider on the product page. I added a second image, the images to slide to the second image works perfectly fine, but he won't show the second image. I found out that the images are under each other, in stead of next to each other. Does someone knows how to fix this? I have tried a lot of things for a couple of hours...

Link to the product with a slider: https://freezing-clothing.nl/product/freezing-stickers/

Kind regards,

Luke

Comment: You can turn off the "overflow:hidden" on the div "flex-viewport", you will see the images are stacked under each other

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)